# How can I set the legend to the top-right corner in a KendoChart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have been using a kendochart as in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ericklanford/6dr0k59v/1/).

I set the legend position as:

```
legend: {
          visible: true,
          position: "custom",
          offsetX: 500
        },
```

but what I really want is show the legend to  top-right corner.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var char = $('#chart').data('kendoChart');    
chart.options.legend.offsetX = $('#chart').width() - 100;
chart.redraw()
```

This way you dynamically adjust legend based on screen resolution.